# Do OS X operating systems use the Unix/Linux structure?

Tags: macos

Yes, there may be possible duplicates, but I am talking about the **STRUCTURE** of Unix/Linux operating systems with folders like bin, home etc. Unix/Linux-based operating systems are supposed to have its structure, OS X is also supposed to have it. Does it?

Comment: You could figure this out yourself by studying this "Structure" and then looking at an OSX systems and observing whether it qualifies. So the question is, what have you tried? What work have you done prior to coming here and asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no such a thing as a standard Unix/Linux filesystem structure. Multiple attempts have been made over decades to define one, but no one really adheres completely.
Even between Linux distros you will find some differences.

Still most Unix and Unix like systems at least have a lot of stuff in common, if only to make porting software between them easier.
MacOS derives most of its underpinnings from BSD Unix and is no different in that regard as this `ls -l` output from `/` shows:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 60 root  admin  1920 Jul  4 00:11 Applications
drwxr-xr-x  71 root  wheel  2272 Jun 10 07:27 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  8 root  wheel   256 Sep 29  2019 System
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin   224 Sep 29  2019 Users
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192 Jul  6 12:07 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 38 root  wheel  1216 Jun 10 07:25 bin
drwxrwxrwx   3 root  wheel    96 Jan  5  2019 com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Aug 25  2019 cores
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  4464 Jun 10 07:31 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  admin    11 Oct  7  2019 etc -> private/etc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    25 Jun 10 07:32 home -> /System/Volumes/Data/home
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Oct  7  2019 opt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192 Jun 10 07:26 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 63 root  wheel  2016 Jun 10 07:25 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  admin    11 Oct  7  2019 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root  wheel   352 Oct  7  2019 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  admin    11 Oct  7  2019 var -> private/var
```